# "is_visible" flag location for Woocommerce products attributes

Tags: mysql, wordpress, attributes, woocommerce

This matter is driving me crazy as after wasting days going through my DB I've still been unable to find out an answer to the following question:

Where is the flag "is_visible" stored on the mysql DB for the attributes of Woocommerce products?

I checked all the tables 1000 times but I can't understand where and how the flag option "attribute visible on the product page" is stored on the Wordpress DB.

Thanks!

Enrico

Comment: Can you describe where you've already checked?

Comment: I did a lot of reversing on the DB: I was able to find out how attributes are stored and related to products running queries (joins) among wp_posts, wp_postmeta wp_woocommerce_termmeta,  wp_woocommerce_attribute_taxonomies, wp_terms, wp_term_relationships, wp_term_taxonomy but the the only "visible" entry that I found was for the posts (which is not relevant).
I was thinking in debugging all the sql queries while changing that value on the WP back-end but unfortunately I can't enable the debugging mode on the DB as I don't have full admin privileges.

Comment: I found where the information is stored: I did a dump of the DB, changed the visibility flag for an attribute and took a new dump: running a diff between the dump I realised that all the attributes data for each product are stored together under the same entry in the wp_postmeta table (the entries were so long that they weren't displayed and not fully viewable from phpMyAdmin!). It's a text value but actually it seems the dump of a php array variable.

Answer (score 4):

the data is sotered in the postmeta table. However it is not quite straight forward to handle it. If you pick a product and do a search for the product ID as post_id you will see a record with the meta_key _product_attributes. In the meta value you will find a serialised array of the attributes including is_visible.

Just be careful because if you simply edit it in phpmyadmin you can mess stuff up badly. If you don't know what a serialised array is google it.

Answer (score 0):

In case someone is searching for this in the year 2022 or later: In the meantime woocommerce isn't storing this value in the post_meta table. Instead there is a taxonomy called "product_visibility" with different states (exclude-from-catalog, exclude-from-search). In the "term_relationships" table is stored which of these values is associated with a product.